# npm run dev:ssr - can we copy files/folders in dist/server before serving using dev:ssr? Angular SSR/universal

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

first thing - it works fine for `npm run build/build:ssr` but it does not work for `dev:ssr` (required for hot reload development)

So, I have backend code which reads from `.pem` file during runtime. I have added another script in `package.json` to copy the .pem's inside the `dist/server` folder.

Problem is this script I can add/run in `build/build:ssr` but not in `dev:ssr`, means it is not working here

My package.json's scripts are:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm run",
    "build": "ng build && npm run cp",
    **"cp": "cpx \"./backend/keys/*.pem\" dist/projectName/server/keys",**
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "dev:ssr": "npm run cp && ng run projectName:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/projectName/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build && ng run projectName:server",
  },
```

so in the above scripts dev:ssr is unable to copy the files as during build a fresh dist is created, any idea other than using nodemon? Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: May be you should try assets configuration with angular workspace https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#asset-config

Comment: @Abbah assets is for UI/Frontend and is stored in broswer folder inside dist. Looking for a way to store in server folder